# performance of java.util.Stack.clear()

Tags: java, stack

Hi I wonder what the performance complexity of java.util.Stack.clear() is.

If it only de-ref the top pf stack then the performance would be O(1),

if it instead delets every single node then the performace would be O(n)

which one is right?

Comment: The source code for the method is readily available. Why not take a look and see what is happening? It's often with your JDK and is called src.zip. It is also available online, but I don't have the reference on my right this moment, although Google can find it.

Comment: You mean: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Stack.java ? ;-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Looking into the source code, good call thanks.  I wonder if you work for StackOverflow! You are always online right there! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.clear%28%29 - looks O(n) to me (plus the GC that will need to be done).

```
 public void clear() {
     removeAllElements();
 }

 public synchronized void removeAllElements() {
     modCount++;
     // Let gc do its work
     for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
         elementData[i] = null;

     elementCount = 0;
 }
```

Comment: But then again, that is implementation specific. Another implementation may just set `elementCount = 0` and wait for new data to clear the old.